# Clearing OpenCL pipes

Tags: opencl

I'm using OCL pipes to pass data across kernels, but would need to clear the pipes after each pass so new data could go in. Is it possible to somehow clear the pipes with each run or does it clear itself each time I use the 'write_pipe' function?

I'm doing essentially this, and I will only be using one pipe ideally:

```
kernel1{
 //read data from host, then write to pipe
}

do..x times
kernel2{
 //read pipe
 //calculations
 //write pipe
}

kernel3{
 //read pipe
 //write to host
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pipe` is a FIFO memory object and gets cleared once you read it.

Note also that a given kernel can either read from or write to a pipe, but not both.

You can read more about pipes + example [here](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/10/31/opencl-2-0-pipes/)

Comment: Is there some workaround to R/W a pipe in a single kernel? Some kind of barriers of sorts or something simiar? I need the data after the calculations of the second kernel to be passed back into it immediately after it ends, when the kernel is called again until the loop is completed. The purpose of using pipes is for optimization, so I don't want the code to pass any data to or from the host in this case.

Comment: Workaround in a single kernel rather not. You will probably need to have 2 kernels (second duplicate or similar) and 2 pipes so that kernel1 writes to pipe1 and reads from pipe2 and kernel2 writes to pipe2 and reads from pipe1.

Comment: is it possible to have the kernels work as such in a general opencl context, say with any graphic card:

`k1: read from host, write pipe0`
`k2: read pipe0, write pipe1`
`k3: read pipe1, write pipe0`
`k4: read pipe0, write to host`
? The code I wrote seems to be working on one device but not another.